# Sticky footer - Which solution

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to keep my footer stuck to the bottom of the page a bit like google does, but I want to do it in the least "hacky" way possible. Since I am new to web design I was wondering if anyone is able to give some input on which method has the benefits:

**Method 1:**
http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

**Method 2:**
http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

**Method 3:** 
jQuery docked footer (along these lines [but not exactly like](http://www.psyklopz.com/workbench/jquery-based-dock-toolbar/))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've all been there at some point or the other. I personally have a preference towards Method #2 (http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/) because it's the least messy of the two. jQuery based solution is a strict NO for me because some users might have JS disabled for whatever reasons!

Answer (score 1):

Could you not just use a css solution? Something like this?

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px; 
left: 0px; 
right: 0px;
width: 100%; 
height: 100px; 
border: 1px solid black;
```

Comment: I conquer that all three methods named are outdated. `position: absolute` and `bottom:0` is enough and oh so easy.

Comment: This keeps it on the page all the time instead of having it pushed down by content, but it is an interesting idea certainly.